# Execute daily job only beetwen two hours in pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I would like to run a Job (Or transformation) in pentaho every tot minutes (I.e. 10 minutes) but only during work time (I.e. starting from 8:00 am to 18:00 pm).

Any suggestion?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by either scheduling the job in cron or in PDI server. A cron string like

```
*/5 8-18 * * *
```

should do the trick. It reads as:

- `*/5` - every 5 minutes
- `8-18` - every hour from 8 to 18
- `* * *` every day and every week-day of every month.

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately I am running the job on a windows machine, I will create a "cron" for windows in this case.

Comment: the windows scheduler most likely has equivalent options.

Comment: in windows, using task scheduler you can directly create a task and specify your kitchen.bat/pan/bat file location.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule jobs and transformations to execute automatically on a recurring basis by following the directions below.(according to [Scheduling Transformations and Jobs From Spoon](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.1/0L0/0Y0/0J0/000))

1. Open a job or transformation, then go to the Action menu and select Schedule.
2. In the Schedule a Transformation dialog box, enter the date and time that you want the schedule to begin in the Start area, or click the calendar icon (circled in red) to display the calendar. To run the transformation immediately, enable the Now radio button.
3. Set up the End date and time. If applicable, enable the No end radio button or click on the calendar and input the date and time to end the transformation.
4. If applicable, set up a recurrence under Repeat.
   End date and time are disabled unless you select a recurrence. From the list of schedule options select the choice that is most appropriate: Run Once, Seconds, Minutes, Hourly, Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Yearly.
5. Make sure you set parameters, arguments and variables, if available. Click OK.
6. In the Spoon button bar, click the Schedule perspective.

From the Schedule perspective, you can refresh, start, pause, stop and delete a transformation or job using the buttons on the upper left corner of the page.

*Also* as @nsousa said , is using system cron to run it with something like the following

```
*/5 8-18 * * * sh -C pan.sh -file:"/Users/zhilevan/pentaho_res/first_test.ktr"
```

Comment: The answer is bit confusing, please edit and mention which command will work on pentaho community and which is for pentaho enterprise so that everyone can understand and don't get confused.